# Join Tables based on date time

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Join two tables based on Date time**

```
CREATE Table A
(StartDate DATETIME, 
EndDate DATETIME,
Name VARCHAR(50))

CREATE Table B
(FromDate DATETIME, 
ToDate DATETIME,
Product VARCHAR(50),
Price VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO A values ('05/20/2014 10:00:00', '05/20/2014 14:00:00', 'Stalin')
INSERT INTO A values ('05/20/2014 14:02:00', '05/20/2014 18:03:00', 'Vipin')
INSERT INTO A values ('05/20/2014 18:10:00', '05/20/2014 23:04:00', 'Raju')


INSERT INTO B values ('05/20/2014 10:01:00', '05/20/2014 14:01:00', 'Pen', '20')
INSERT INTO B values ('05/20/2014 14:02:33', '05/20/2014 18:03:58', 'Pensil', '22')
INSERT INTO B values ('05/20/2014 18:11:00', '05/20/2014 23:05:00', 'Book','33')
```

Result should be

```
StartDate           EndDate            FromDate        ToDate           Product    Price    Name
5/20/2014 10:00 | 5/20/2014 14:00 | 5/20/2014 10:01 | 5/20/2014 14:01 | Pen      |   20   | Stalin
5/20/2014 14:02 | 5/20/2014 18:03 | 5/20/2014 14:02 | 5/20/2014 18:03 | Pensil   |   22   | Vipin
5/20/2014 18:10 | 5/20/2014 23:04 | 5/20/2014 18:11 | 5/20/2014 23:05 | Book     |   33   | Raju
```

I am trying the following query

```
Select A.StartDate,a.EndDate, b.FromDate, b.ToDate, b.Product,b.Price,a.Name 
from a
Join B 
ON A.StartDate BETWEEN DATEADD(MM,-2,B.FromDate) 
AND DATEADD(MM,2,B.ToDate)
```

result is not as expected, any help ?

Comment: He showed the expected results... he doesn't show what he is getting, though

Comment: In `DateAdd` `MM` stand for month, that's probably why your query is not working as expected

Answer (score 0):

All the dates are within 2 months of each other.  I assume you really want minutes.  Try this:

```
Select A.StartDate,a.EndDate, b.FromDate, b.ToDate, b.Product, b.Price,a.Name
from a Join
     B
     ON A.StartDate BETWEEN DATEADD(minute,-2,B.FromDate) AND DATEADD(minute,2,B.ToDate);
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) is the list of valid date parts.

When using functions such as `dateadd()` and `datepart()`, use the full name of the unit.  There is no reason to use abbreviations.  Even if you think you know what `MM` means, someone else reading your code may not readily know.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for

```
SELECT  A.StartDate,
        A.EndDate,
        B.FromDate,
        B.ToDate,
        B.Product,
        B.Price,
        A.Name
FROM    A
JOIN    B ON DATEPART(HH,A.StartDate) = DATEPART(HH,B.FromDate)
AND     CAST(A.StartDate AS DATE) = CAST(B.FromDate AS DATE)
```

Obtained result

[image]